# How to tell if a tire should be replaced?

Tags: road-bike, tire

I don’t know how old this tire is. There are small cracks along the sides. In the inside the rubber coating is stripping and peeling. Is this tire still usable? Air has been going out of my tube rapidly lately, in about a day, but I’m not sure it’s from a puncture, maybe a bad valve.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Slow leaks happen because of bad valve or very small puncture. These are often difficult to find and valves can't really be repaired, so the best option is to replace the tube. Personally, I would also replace these tires.

Comment: Definitely needs replacing. With that amount of degradation and rubber falling off the tire will be weakened. If the inner tube looks anything like that replace it too.

Comment: Given the very serious injuries that can result from a tire failure and crash, I think it makes very little sense to trust those tires.  Definite replace.

Comment: Apart from the obvious, the tread rubber will be hardened and not provide the same grip as a new tire.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tire's job is to (not a complete list):

1. Stay attached to the rim
2. Protect the tube from damage
3. Contain the pressure inside the tube (this is why the pressure rating is on the tire and not the tube)
4. Provide a good connection to the ground

Tubeless tires also do the job of the tube.

The tube's job is to:

1. Hold air

In the drawing below you have a "Clincher" tire.

[image]
[A simple guide on the essentials of wheels, rims, and tyres](https://www.betterbybicycle.com/2014/04/a-simple-guide-on-essentials-of-wheels.html)

You have two different problems.

- Your tire is badly oxidized which compromises it's ability to do all four of the things listed above. You need to replace the tire.
- Your tube is leaking air. This has nothing to do with the condition of the tire. You need to find the leak and replace or repair the tube.